# how to acpi shutdown in assembly in custom os?

Tags: assembly, virtualbox, shutdown, acpi, dsdt

I am running a custom os in virtualbox and have parsed the ACPI, FACP, DSDT etc tables to get the PM1a_CNT and SLP_TYPa values.  These seem to be correct.  However when I try to do an ACPI shutdown with:

```
xor eax, eax
mov edx, [PM1a_CNT]
mov ax, [SLP_TYPa]
or ax, (1 shl 13)
out dx, ax
```

Nothing happens. `PM1a_CNT` is 0x4004 and `SLP_TYPa` is 0, which seems reasonable compared to other values I have seen elsewhere.  I also check PM1b_CNT which is zero so I don't bother with it.

Is there an issue or trick with virtualbox to get it working?

Answer (score 2):

Everything looks correct except that you're writing a 32-bit value to a 16-bit I/O port. Try replacing the final `out dx, eax` with `out dx, ax`.

Comment: Yeah I initially used ax, didn't work, so I tried eax.  Forgot to change it back when pasting the code.  Will fix it.

Comment: So changing it doesn't fix your problem?

Comment: No, like I said, I originally used ax and it didn't work